# How to copy observable collection

Tags: wpf, copy, observablecollection

I have

```
Observablecollection<A> aRef = new Observablecollection<A>();
bRef = aRef();
```

In this case both point to same `ObservableCollection`. How do I make a different copy?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do this:

```
// aRef being an Observablecollection 
Observablecollection<Entity> bRef = new Observablecollection<Entity>(aRef);
```

This will create an observable collection but the items are still pointing to the original items.  If you need the items to point a clone rather than the original items, you need to implement and then call a cloning method.

**UPDATE**

If you try to add to a list and then the observable collection have the original list, just create the Observablecollection by passing the original list:

```
List<Entity> originalEnityList = GetThatOriginalEnityListFromSomewhere();
Observablecollection<Entity> bRef = new Observablecollection<Entity>(originalEnityList);
```

Comment: Thanks...But my real issue is I have an observable collection...when i add a new item to it..it's not getting reflected in UI. So what I am doing now is copy whole collection to a temperory collection...then add new item to temp collection. Then assign back the temp collection back.

Comment: But I have observable collection as input. Ie....I have an observable collection of 120 items..I add new item to it..now it has 121 items...Then UI should display 121 items

Comment: SO there is not a way.  Observablecollection does not expose the original list. You have to expose the original list mate.

Comment: Can we use "All", "Select" methods to get a new observable collection ?

Comment: The point is that you are adding to the original list and you want the new OC to show your changes. All or Select will create a new list. But why do you want to use a new OC anyway? Just bind the old OC to a new control, that is all you seem to need.

Comment: you have to use two way binding so that if there is any change in the original observable collection then it will be reflected.

Answer (score 11):

You could implement `ICloneable` interface in you entity definition and then make a copy of the `ObservableCollection` with a internal cast. As a result you will have a cloned `List` without any reference to old items. Then you could create your new `ObservableCollection` whit the cloned  `List`

```
public class YourEntity : ICloneable {
    public AnyType Property { get; set; }
    ....
    public object Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

The implementation would be

```
var clonedList = originalObservableCollection.Select(objEntity => (YourEntity) objEntity.Clone()).ToList();

ObservableCollection<YourEntity> clonedCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourEntity>(clonedList);
```

Comment: That is not working when originalObservableCollection is binded. When you change something in it, clonedCollection get's changes too.